# Is it too soon to contact prospective PI's for postdoc or research positions if im one month away from my PhD oral defense?

Tags: postdocs

I am an international PhD student in Taiwan. I am scheduled to have my oral defense next month. I don't see any foreseeable problem that might happen during that time, but I still make sure I'm prepared. While trying to manage the stress of the coming oral defense, I'm also thinking about the future. After the oral defense, I will stay for one year before leaving the country. I want to apply for postdocs or research positions in Canada, specifically in Calgary. Is it too soon to contact PI's about a position?

Comment: If you're looking to start a postdoc in 2024 then it is definitely not too early to start reaching out to academics. Although many PI's may still not know about their potential funding. (Most positions begin to be advertised over the next few months).

Comment: Thank you for the valuable comment.

Answer (score 2):

My PI used to say that the deadline to do anything in academia is "yesterday". Although a PI may not know for sure whether they will have funding or open positions in 13 months, it is never too early to start expressing your interest for their lab and to start discussing research topic and collaborations. The worst they can answer is "please contact me again later". And that would leave you plenty of time to look for your own funding.

Answer (score -1):

Yes, it is too soon to contact PI for positions that will be open in ~13 months for now.

However, it is not too soon to getting in touch with potential hosts (as a postdoc, what you define PIs can be your host and you can be the PI) to get accostumed to possible source of funding.

Since you are looking for a specific place, it will be much easier to bring there your "own" funds (i.e. getting a project of your own funded) rather than getting a postdoc position there.

Disclaimer: much easier means still "very hard".

Comment: I am curious about this and might be asking a dumb question, but how do you even do that? "get a funded project before getting hired by the host PI?". Does that mean finding a PI and writing a grant proposal with them, and getting hired if it gets funding?

Comment: PI means Principal Investigator. PI makes sense only internally in a project. no project = no PI.
You may be employed, or affiliated, or a guest at a certain department, with or without a salary. This does not prevent you to write a proposal. But often for the proposal you need to define a PI and an hosting institution/department.

You can be the Principal Investigator, then there is a department hosting you, and in the hosting department there will be someone willing to support you.

Comment: A short and not complete list of possible funding sources in Canada (specific to Ottawa, you may find similar stuff for Calgary):
https://www.uottawa.ca/study/graduate-studies/postdoctoral-fellowships-external-agencies#:~:text=External%20postdoctoral%20funding%20sources%20include,Council%20of%20Canada%20(SSHRC).
good luck!